Accessing personal computer remotely (Ubuntu) without VPN
I would like to use my work computer to access my home computer while in the office, motivation for this is that I will be able to install whatever packages and tools to play with on my home computer without worrying too much about security policies implied by IT team (having subset of PIP packages to install from, inability to install open source tools ...) . Another limitation is that I cannot use a VPN to access my home network, which is prohibited.
So in essence, I want to know if there is a secure and free way to remotely access my personal computer through my work computer with no VPN.

If your home computer is connected through a public IP, you might be able to use ssh to connect to it.

Is that same as having a fixed IP ? if so , then no I do not have that
My home network is using 4G modem connected to a WIFI router

@AlaBek It's not the same as a fixed ip. But in this case you would need some dynamic dns provider to know what your current ip address is and forward the ssh port to your home computer.

If you have a dedicated public IP address at home, then a VPN is optional – you can connect directly to your home router's address and use 'port forwarding' to reach internal devices. (It does require some additional care to keep the SSH server secure.)
If you don't have a dedicated IP address (i.e. you're behind a CGNAT), call your ISP to see if you can order one (might be anywhere from "no" to "what's that" to $2/month, depending on the ISP). Yes you can technically get a static IP address on 4G.
You can also have some other host that has a public IP address relay the connections to you. For example, you can rent a VPS and set up any kind of VPN between your home and the VPS, then configure it so that you could connect to the public IP address of the VPS and it would relay connections home through that VPN. There are free services that relay HTTP requests (e.g. ngrok and similar) and some of them can also relay TCP connections for SSH.
Make sure your workplace allows this in general.
